# Pause jQuery effect during execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, hover, mouseover

My website has some icons that glows on mouse over but I want it to glow randomly when no one is hovering.

Right now I have the correct piece of codes that will make it randomly glow and glow on hover but how to make the random glow stop and resume after a person has hovered over the icons.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't provided much information, this is what I would think of doing:

1. Create a function that glows an icon
2. Create another function that calls glow function on random icons
3. Create a timer(Interval) to keep calling randomGlow function at a set interval
4. Attach a mouseenter event for the icon such that, when fired, it would clear the timer and call glow on that icon only. And when mouseout, it starts a new timer. (timer is global)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) to cease any existing effects.

However there isn't (AFAIK) any way to *resume* those effects once the additional effects started by your hover have finished.

You'd have to restart your "random" glowing in the second `.hover()` callback.

**EDIT** it *may* be possible, but this is untested:

1. call `.queue()` to get the current animation queue, and copy the results
2. call `.stop()` to remove all those
3. do your new animations
4. in `.hover()`'s "out" function, re-instate the queued items from #1 above

Comment: Thanks Alnitak, your suggestion makes sense. Let me give it a try.

Comment: @JamesWong see http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/mS99A/ - it's _mostly_ working.  However it's not possible to reinstate the "inprogress" animation, and if there's nothing else left after the whole animation stops.  You'd need to check the resulting queue, and restart the random animation if nothing else is left.

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if they icon is glowing before you glow it:

```
$('.icon').hover(function() {
    $(this).stop(true, true);
    $(this).toggleClass('glow', true);
}, function() {
    $(this).stop(true, true);
    $(this).toggleClass('glow', false);
});

function randomglow(icon) {
    if (!$(icon).hasClass('glow')) {
        //your glow code here
    }
}
```